# rviz camera orientation controlled by oculus rift

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am interested in displaying a pointcloud in rviz and allowing a user to view the point cloud using the oculus rift. Is there a plugin which displays rviz views to the oculus and publishes pose from the oculus? Googling has produced no solutions for me thus far. I am using ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237946/rviz-camera-orientation-controlled-by-oculus-rift/) by [hasfuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27269/hasfuraa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [oculus_rivz_plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/oculus_rviz_plugins) package displays the 3D view in rviz within the oculus rift, allows the user to move their head to change the orientation of the view, and publishes the `/oculus` TF frame representing the pose of the oculus.

It's been released on ROS Indigo, but it should work reasonably well on later versions of ROS too.

The wiki page provides only minimal documentation; you can learn more by reading the [source code on github](http://wiki.ros.org/oculus_rviz_plugins) and by reading the issues in [their issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-visualization/oculus_rviz_plugins/issues)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0